# What does "because why not" mean?

Tags: meaning, grammar

I want you to help.
I don't speak English that much.
So, I couldn't understand this sentence while studying today.
Is this a slang? How do you use this sentence?

Comment: It means "for no specific reason". You should read that as short for "because... well, why not?".

Comment: The question from the title seems good, but this question would be better if you included more information about where you found the phrase.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This phrase is used as an argument (usually by someone who is **for** doing something). Consider the following:

> **A**: But why would we do that? I don't see how we gain much.
>
> **B**: Because why not?

B is arguing that instead of looking at the reasons *to* do something, they should instead be looking at how little they have to lose.

See also:

> #### [why-not, n.](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/228836?rskey=F3QFpz&result=2&isAdvanced=false#eid)
>
> 1. An argument of the form ‘Why not?’, which attempts to leave the opponent without a reply.

---

It's also worth noting that a response to "because why not?" has actually evolved in internet usage to "because X." For a thorough and awesome write-up, read [here](https://allthingslinguistic.com/post/72252671648/why-the-new-because-isnt-a-preposition-but-is).